# Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm probably missing something but why does this work fine for a Picker but not for a List? I don't see why it is complaining about a missing parameter type.

```
struct ContentView: View {
enum FooBar: CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    public var id : String { UUID().uuidString }
    
    case foo
    case bar
    case buzz
    case bizz
}

@State var selectedFooBar: FooBar = .bar

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Picker("Select", selection: $selectedFooBar) {
            ForEach(FooBar.allCases) { item in
                Text(self.string(from: item)).tag(item)
            }
        }
        
        List(FooBar.allCases, selection: $selectedFooBar) { item in
            Text(self.string(from: item)).tag(item)
        }
        
        Text("You selected: \(self.string(from: selectedFooBar))")
    }
}


private func string(from item: FooBar) -> String {
    var str = ""
    
    switch item {
    case .foo:
        str = "Foo"
        
    case .bar:
        str = "Bar"
        
    case .buzz:
        str = "Buzz"
        
    case .bizz:
        str = "Bizz"
    }
    return str
}
}
```

I tried to find explanations and examples but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The selected item has the right type `FooBar` for the picker but the wrong type for the list. if you used `Set<String>` then the compiler will not complain

```
@State var selectedFooBar: FooBar = .bar
@State var selectedItems: Set<String>

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Picker("Select", selection: $selectedFooBar) {
            ForEach(FooBar.allCases) { item in
                Text(self.string1(from: item)).tag(item)
            }
        }

        List(FooBar.allCases, selection: $selectedItems) { item in
            Text(self.string1(from: item))
        }



        Text("You selected: \(self.string1(from: selectedFooBar))")
    }
```

Note that the list will need to be in "Edit mode" to use selection.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the list out to it's own variable outside of `body`:

```
var list: some View {
        List(FooBar.allCases, selection: $selectedFooBar) { item in
            Text(self.string(from: item)).tag(item)
        }
    }
```

...You get this error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'List<_, _>' with an argument list of type '([ContentView.FooBar], selection: Binding<ContentView.FooBar>, @escaping (ContentView.FooBar) -> some View)'"

It looks like you're trying to use the same initializer from Picker on List, but they are quite different.  Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
List {
            ForEach(FooBar.allCases) { item in
                Text(self.string(from: item)).tag(item)
            }
        }
```